# C# start process as administrator and credentials works only with cmd

Tags: c#, admin, process.start, runas

I am trying to start a program which need administrator rights in C#. Unfortunately, I have to store the account data in the code, but this is not to be discussed. If I try to execute the exe directly I get the error that the process requires elevated rights, which the account has. If I run a cmd or powershell and give it the command to start the program in the argument section it works. The program is located in a place where every user has access to it.
I've already tried every possible parameter I could find. Here is some example code:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
        //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c start exe;
        //proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
        proc.StartInfo.Domain = domain;
        proc.StartInfo.UserName = user;
        for (int x = 0; x < pass.Length; x++)
        {
            ssPwd.AppendChar(pass[x]);
        }
        proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
        proc.Start();
```

Comment: What is the problem do you have? Run it without cmd?

Comment: If I run it without cmd, I get the error, that the process needs elevated rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

**Rightclick on Project** -> **Add new Item** -> **Add Application Manifest file**.
Now, change/add the line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Once saved, the application will run.

Or you can do the following:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
   FileName = <path to file name here>,
   UserName = "admin",
   Domain = "",
   Password = "password here",
   UseShellExecute = false,
   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
   RedirectStandardError = true
};

Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the goal is to start a program as an administrator with stored data as a standard user. Therefore option 1 does not work. With option 2 I get the error message that increased rights would be necessary, which are given.